# Highcharts custom symbol

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular5

I am trying to add custom symbol in angular 5 project.

This is my code:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line, function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x`enter code here`+height,y + width / 2];
}
```

I am getting following error:

> ERROR in src/app/dashboard/apc-hse-monthly-chart/apc-hse-monthly-chart.component.ts(29,16): error TS2339: Property 'Renderer' does not exist on type 'typeof import("D:/source/QHSE/QHSE_Frontend/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts")'.

What is the correct way to do this in angular 5?

Comment: You can get more idea about highcharts from here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_highcharts/angular_highcharts_configuration_syntax.htm Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
 return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
```

relace Render with SVGRenderer